# Run 'query session' from python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

So I am making a program in python that will report the users on a system who connected with RGS.

One way to get users on windows is the `query session` command.
I have tried with both `os.popen` and `subprocess.Popen` with and without shell=True. I even specified the full path of the command.

All I get is this error:

```
'C:/Windows/System32/query.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I can get it working using PsLoggedon.exe, but that wont tell me session type.

So I guess my question is: how can I get this command to work, or what is another way to address this problem?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

args = ['C:\\Windows\\system32\\query.exe', 'user']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = process.communicate()

users = [line[1:].split('  ')[0] for line in output.strip().split('\n')[1:]]
print(users)
```

Prints `['poke']` for me.

Comment: For 32-bit Python running on 64-bit Windows, use `args = [r'C:\Windows\Sysnative\query.exe', 'user']`. There's no 32-bit build of query.exe.

Comment: @eryksun, that must be it. Thanks!