# Python 'os.system' cant execute windows console query

Tags: python, terminal, console

I have to get the user, whos logged onto a PC in the network.

If I go to the terminal on Windows 10 and type "query user server:'PC-Name'", I get the user whos logged onto this machine.

But If I try to run this query in python with os.system like that:

```
import os
test = os.system("query user")
```

From the Code above I get the Error "The query 'query' has a typo or cant be found."

Can someone tell me, why I can send every query like ping, tracert, ipconfig etc but not query user ? And why does it work, if I type it into the terminal and not, if I try the same thing with os.system ?

Greetings :)

EDIT:

It works now with the following code:

```
import os
test = os.system(r"c:\windows\sysnative\query.exe user")
print(test)
```

So now I get the output of the query, but it returns just a "1". Can I access the username which is included in the terminal output of "query user" ?

Comment: I tried the same in windows 7 and windows 10 using both os and subprocess. works fine for me. Am i missing something?

Comment: I ran your code on my server, it executed successfully. Try to run it with full path to query.exe: `os.system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\query.exe user")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run 'query session' from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378740/run-query-session-from-python)

Comment: the error message indicates you are doing something like `query query user`.  Can you double check?  Failing that, on the command-line `echo %comspec%`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev I tried that before. Same result. I checked the file and it's unter Windows\System32.

Comment: @Guoliang Similiar, but dont work in my case. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also if I print "test", it gets me an "1". If that helps.

Comment: @lordzwieback return code 1..hmm.. which means the command execution has failed.

Comment: @lordzwieback If you have to just get the user who has logged into the machine, you could try this - `os.getenv("USERNAME")`. It works on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @KartikKannapur that returns the user whos logged in on the PC where the script is executed. I need something, where I can check remote clients in the network.